# Showing/Hiding div

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am using asp.net ajax control toolkit 1.0 on vs 2005. I am using the collapseablePanel and AlwaysVisibleControlExtender control. When I use these, I notice that it my panel flashes for a few seconds before it is hidden.

To avoid this, I have decided to place it in  a div  to make it hidden.
I want it shown when I use the control.

Here is what I have:

```
<div id="menuContent" style="display:none">

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddNewContent" runat="server" Width="300px">
   ....//the panel stuff here
 </asp>
</div>
```

and the javascript for this in the header is:

```
    function showdiv() { 
    if (document.getElementbyId) {
        document.getElementbyId('menuContent').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    } 

    }
```

(its for IE 6 for I don't care about compatability)

and body onload=onLoad="showdiv();"

It correctly hides upon load, but I cannot get it to show again. Does anyone have solutions?

Comment: n.b. changing visibility preserves the rendered layout space, changing display alteres the rendered layout (such that display:none effectively collapses the element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically had to use Visibility hidden and visible attributes as these work best on a collapsePanel

Comment: actually doesnt work properly.... :(
See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925060/showing-hiding-div-collapsepanel-after-clientscript-registerclientscriptblock

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to show it by setting the visibility but you hid it using display.

You actually want something like this:

document.getElementbyId('menuContent').style.display = 'block';

Comment: thanks, I did it but used hidden and visible using visibility.
Your one didn't work properly on the collapsePanel the way I wished it to be implem,ented.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I suggested the display style over visible as the display removes the content from the page where as visible just makes it invisible but still takes up the space it would have on the page, this can lead to big blank holes on your page, where as display will (or should) make everything move up to take its place which is the more common approach.

Comment: Thanks, and can u help with this question pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925060/showing-hiding-div-collapsepanel-after-clientscript-registerclientscriptblock

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for

Javascript function:

```
function showHide(descriptor) 
{    
    var layer = document.getElementById(descriptor);
    if (layer != null) {
        if (layer.style.display != 'none') {
            layer.style.display = 'none'; //hide layer              
        } else {
            layer.style.display = 'block';//show layer
        }       
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:showHide('divInfo');"><img id="imgInfo" src="info.gif" border="0" /></a>
<div style="display: none;" id="divInfo">some info</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I did it but used hidden and visible using visibility. Your one didn't work properly on the collapsePanel the way I wished it to be implem,ented.